# Writing to a file (python)

Tags: python, file, io

```
     if data.find('!add') != -1:
       f = open('masters.txt', 'w')
       f.writelines(args, '\n')
       sck.send('PRIVMSG ' + chan + ' :' + ' added' + " " + args + '\r\n')
       f.close()
```

When I use this code it replaces the old data with the new data, how can I make it so that the new data doesnt replaced the old data but ends at the end of the file.

Comment: 'w' mode WRITES over everything. 'a' APPENDS. enjoy :)

Comment: RTFM? http://docs.python.org/tutorial/inputoutput.html, section 7.2.

Answer (score 7):

use

```
f = open('masters.txt', 'a')
```

instead

EDIT: see [here](http://cplus.about.com/od/learningc/ss/files_4.htm)

Answer (score 5):

`f = open('masters.txt', 'a')`

Answer (score 0):

Opening the file in 'w' mode deletes everything and then writes new stuff.
I've learned it the hard way ;)

Anyway, you should open it in 'a' mode (append), which would look like this:

```
f = open("masters.txt", 'a')
f.writelines(args, "\n")
f.close()
```